# Falta de tradução ao responder a própria pergunta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Ao responder minha própria pergunta notei que o botão para "prosseguir" está em Inglês.

[image: Imagem com o botão em Inglês]

> **Nota:** ao fazer a pergunta não marquei o campo **Responder sua própria pergunta**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvido.

Traduzido para:

> Sim, quero responder

Estou aberto a sugestões melhores

Comment: Só para manter congruência entre pergunta e resposta, deverias ser "Sim, quero responder".

Comment: @JorgeB. De acordo. Tá corrigido.